# Display the row depended on the checkbox in the row using css

Tags: css

I have a table. The row of the table has checkbox and others control. I only want to print the row which the checkbox is check. I have searched the web and didn't find the solution. Hope someone can help me. thanks in advance

There is my css for pint

```
#pageTest .dgrd td input[type=checkbox]:checked+tr::before{
          display: none;
```

}

There is my html:

```
<table>
   <tr class="dgrdRed">
     <td style="width: 140px;"> 
       <span class="checkBoxClass"><input name="dgrd$ctl15$chkCheckBox" id="dgrd_ctl15_chkCheckBox" type="checkbox"></span>
     </td>
     <td>
        <span id="dgrd_ctl15_lbl"><br>BOWEE</span>
     </td>
   </tr>
   <tr class="dgrdRed">
     <td style="width: 140px;">                     
         <span class="inputCheckBox"><input name="dgrd$ctl16$chkCheckBox"   id="dgrd_ctl16_chkCheckBox" type="checkbox"></span>
    </td>
    <td>
       <span id="dgrd_ctl16_lbl"><br>BOLT</span>
      </td>

    </tr>
   </table>
```

Comment: unchecked should not be displayed, and checked should be displayed. Right?

Comment: Which tag has id = "pageTest" and class= "dgrd"  ?

Comment: In css you have no selector to get a parent. What you can do is to take the inputs ahead of the table, restyle a lable where the input is standing, so you can use sibbling and child selector to hide a specific row

Comment: @DhavalJardosh, yes

Comment: @HimanshuShekhar,  pageTest is body id and dgrd is datagrid id

Comment: **CSS can not do anything for you with this HTML structure**. Mind JS to update your print style sheet.

Answer (score 0):

Use `@media print` CSS...

```
@media print {
   #pageTest .dgrd td input[type=checkbox]:checked+tr::before{
        display: none;
   }
}
```